# Lua override class function in included file

Tags: class, lua, include, overriding

I'm sorry I'm new to LUA scripts and I have to work on code written by others.
Please don't focus on code, my problem is only about included files and priority evaluating which function has to be called, in case of overriding.

Let's say I have a file Terrain.lua containing a class Terrain, which has a function Terrain:generate() and Terrain:generate() calls Terrain:getLatitude().

Terrain was included in a script MyScript.lua, which overrided Terrain:getLatitude() as follows:

```
include("Terrain");

    function Terrain:getLatitude()
       new code;
    end

    function myFunction()   
        local myTerrain = Terrain.create();
        myTerrain.generate();
    end
```

This has the effect of overriding getLatitude(): when myTerrain.generate() is called, generate() is the code from the included "Terrain", **but** getLatitude() **is the local function with the new code**, even if called by a function from the included class.

Now let's say I want to put some of the code in an external file Custom.lua. Custom (and not MyScript) has to override getLatitude().
This is the situation:

Terrain.lua contains Terrain class and these functions

```
Terrain.create()
Terrain.generate()
Terrain.getLatitude()
```

MyScript.lua is the script being executed, and include Custom:

```
include("Custom");

        function myFunction()   
            return customFunction()
        end
```

Custom.lua contains:

```
include("Terrain");

    function Terrain:getLatitude()
       new code;
    end

    function customFunction()   
        local myTerrain = Terrain.create();
        myTerrain.generate();
    end
```

Now, if I call customFunction() from MyScript, getLatitude() from Terrain is used, instead of getLatitude() from Custom. I assume ovveride is possible only inside the currenti file being executed? How can I achieve overriding in an included file?

I hope this example is enough to understand my problem, without posting a lot of code. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what `include()` does (this is not a standard Lua function), but I guess it is equivalent to `require`, so after the line `include("Custom");` function `getLatitude` is already overridden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, some corrections: there is no `local function`'s in your question; `include` is not part of any lua standard, what that **function** actually does may be quite important.

Finally, Lua does not have actual class system, what you use in the question is merely a syntactic sugar (misleading and confusing as I find it) over table assignments. Lua is an interpreted language, so what may seem to you as a class definition is not a static structure known from the very beginning of the program execution but a code that gets executed from the top of the file to the bottom.

Thus, if we assume that `include` is similar to the `require`, then the your question code will be equivalent to the following:

```
do--terrain.lua
 Terrain = {
    create=function() 
        local created_object
        --some code to assign value to created_object
        return created_object
    end
 }

 Terrain.generate = function(self) end

 Terrain.getLatitude = function(this_is_a_self_too) 
    --some code that uses `also_self` as a reference to the object when called as object:generate()
 end

 --do end block is essentially an equivalent of file, its local variables are not seen outside
 --global variables it has assigned (like `terrain`) will stay accessible AFTER its end
 --changes it done to global variables will also remain
end

do--Custom.lua
    Terrain.getLatitude = function(this)--this is the assignment to a field in a table stored in the global variable Terrain
       --this function will replace the one assigned to the `getLatitude` field
    end

    customFunction = function()   
        local myTerrain = Terrain.create();
        myTerrain.generate();--this one probably needs `:` instead of `.`  
        --depends on actual code inside terrain.lua
    end
end

do--MyScript.lua
    myFunction= function()   
        return customFunction() --this line calls the global variable customFunction
    end
end
```

Thus if your actual setup is similar to the one in question, then the "override" will take effect after the Custom.lua is executed and for all the subsequent calls to the `Terrain.getLatitude` regardless of whether or not they've called the file. (And any later file can override it again, and all calls after that will be using the new one)

It is probably more complicated to do a limited override in this setup. That again depends on the actual details of how your team has defined the Terrain class and the class system itself.